# OK to use "capstone" as an adjective?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, compounds

The term "capstone project" is common.  Google tells me there's also something called "Capstone Classroom."

The dictionary -- whatever dictionary you might look in -- says "capstone" is only ever a noun, so I guess these are compound nouns.

All this said, what should I conclude about the sentence

> This is the capstone failure of my life.

Anything wrong with that?  Can I use "capstone" as an adjective with any noun?

Comment: Noun as adjective: http://www.englishleap.com/grammar/noun-as-adjective

Comment: I tend to think of "capstone" as a positive thing... I don't think I would use it to modify a negative idea.

Comment: @Catija - ...unless we were aiming for some deliberately ironic language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Any** noun can be used as an adjective — consider *fence post, door hinge* — although some are more common than others. *Capstone* would be unusual; a more regular adjective might be *supreme* or *crowning*.

Using a slightly unusual turn of phrase is a good way of drawing attention to it. Celebrating a **failure** with a word like *capstone* strikes me as being a rather esoteric use of language.

Comment: I'd add that it's often better to avoid the noun if there is a reasonably well-known related adjective. There's no such adjective for *capstone* though, so I wouldn't hesitate to use it adjectivally for something which similarly was necessary for the success of other elements. I agree that it seems strange with failure though, arguably logical but one has to think too much about why its logical before seeing the logic for it to work smoothly, unless perhaps we've just had a character musing on the failure of a physical capstone or something to back up the metaphor.